# Selenium: how to handle dropdown overlapping that is preventing from clicking on to next element

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to select a list option from the dropdown by sending text (ie; one of the option is: "MyName") to search bar for the dropdown option,  (typeAheadInputSelection). After enter the text the selection is typed on the search bar and option is highlighted, however, the highlighted drop down list does not disappear after hitting enter button.
I'm able to type text and press enter (or tab) however, the selected dropdown overlaps and unable to move onto next web element to take actions.

I have tried below code:
IWebelement webElement= driver.FindElement(By.Id("userType");
webElement.SendKeys("name" + Keys.tab)

Comment: Please add the page source to understand it or provide more detail to answer your question.

Comment: Thank you @Akzy. I have update the questions. please let me know if that helps.

Comment: can you share the URL so we can help you more efficiently